# ADO.NET Calls Synchronously?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Say you have a situation like this:

In your application code, you execute a stored procedure by calling the ExecuteNonQuery() ADO.NET method.  Say that stored procedure takes 30 seconds to complete (typically).

You next call is to another stored procedure.  But the second stored procedure requires the first stored procedure to be completed so it can execute properly.

I'm guessing this is a no-brainer question, and my assumption is that it happens synchronously so that it shouldn't be a problem.  My guess is that the stored procedures (and the code that calls them) will happen linearly.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: *Assuming* that there is only a single thread (across all processes/machines) which executes this code prior to the successful completion of the commit... (while ADO.NET itself is "blocking" in this regard the larger context might not be).

Comment: Unsolicited Advice: You can perform both of them Asynchronously if you use Tasks and properly set up the dependencies between them, they will still happen in order, but they won't block the rest of your program flow.

Comment: @Cpfohl I actually want to block program flow.  This is a dedicated Windows Service making these calls.  If my interval is (for argument's sake) 20 seconds on the timer, and these stored procedures take 30 seconds, I want the timer to pause execution until all of the business/data access logic is finished.  Does that make sense?

Comment: IIRC, ADO.NET is not thread-safe; more specifically, you must *not* use the same `IDbConnection` object on different threads to execute several requests asynchronously. Instead, you will need one separate connection per thread. I cannot remember where exactly I read about this, but it was somewhere in the MSDN reference documentation.

Comment: @stakx I think you remember correctly, but connecting with an identical connection string multiple places at a time is fine, the pooling is pretty intelligent.  (this might not be guaranteed, my statement is purely 'in practice' not 'in theory').

Comment: @Cpfohl Yes, that would be correct.  The SPID would be a different one for the new connection, even with the login/credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 3):

All calls to ExecuteNonQuery are synchronous. Using stored procedures or not has no relevance to the execution model.